# Default OOBX EditForm disappeared for a SharePoint document library

Tags: sharepoint

Default OOBX EditForm disappeared for a SharePoint document library. We tried to create a new edit form in SharePoint designer but got an error that **Could not save the List Changes to Server**. 
Then tried another approach, go to All files/Documentlibrary/Forms -- here got **list view threshold** error. We have more than 10 thousands items in the library, can't open up forms folder.

Please advise how to get the default edit form back.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do it through PowerShell:

```
$webpartTemplate = @"
<WebPart xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
    <Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>  
    <TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListFormWebPart</TypeName>
    <ListName xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListForm">{{{LIST_ID}}}</ListName>
    <ListId xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListForm">{{LIST_ID}}</ListId>
    <PageType xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListForm">{{PAGE_TYPE}}</PageType>
    <FormType xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListForm">{{FORM_TYPE}}</FormType>
    <ControlMode xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListForm">{{CONTROL_MODE}}</ControlMode>
    <ViewFlag xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListForm">1048576</ViewFlag>
    <ViewFlags xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListForm">Default</ViewFlags>
    <ListItemId xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListForm">0</ListItemId>
</WebPart>
"@

Function Create-DefaultListForm
{
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$List, 
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$FormUrl, 
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][ValidateSet("Display", "Edit", "New")]$FormType
    )

    begin { }    
    process
    {

        $webpartXml = $webpartTemplate -replace "{{LIST_ID}}", $List.Id.ToString()

        switch ($FormType)
        {
            "Display" { 
                $webpartXml = $webpartXml -replace "{{PAGE_TYPE}}", "PAGE_DISPLAYFORM" 
                $webpartXml = $webpartXml -replace "{{FORM_TYPE}}", "4"  
                $webpartXml = $webpartXml -replace "{{CONTROL_MODE}}", "Display"  
                break;
            }
            "Edit" { 
                $webpartXml = $webpartXml -replace "{{PAGE_TYPE}}", "PAGE_EDITFORM" 
                $webpartXml = $webpartXml -replace "{{FORM_TYPE}}", "6"  
                $webpartXml = $webpartXml -replace "{{CONTROL_MODE}}", "Edit"  
                break;
            }
            "New" { 
                $webpartXml = $webpartXml -replace "{{PAGE_TYPE}}", "PAGE_NEWFORM" 
                $webpartXml = $webpartXml -replace "{{FORM_TYPE}}", "8"  
                $webpartXml = $webpartXml -replace "{{CONTROL_MODE}}", "New"  
                break;
            }
        }

        try
        {           
            #Check if form page already exists
            $listPages = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $List.RootFolder -Property Files
            $formPage = $listPages | Where-Object { $_.ServerRelativeUrl.ToLower() -eq $FormUrl.ToLower() }

            if ($null -eq $formPage) {
                Write-Output "  [Creating Form Page] $FormUrl"

                #Create Form
                Remove-PnPFile -ServerRelativeUrl $FormUrl -Force
                $formPage = $List.RootFolder.Files.AddTemplateFile($FormUrl, [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.TemplateFileType]::FormPage)            
            }
            else {
                #Form page exists, check if form is recognized by list (i.e. form page has a form webpart on it)
                $listForms = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $List -Property Forms

                if ($null -ne $listForms -and $listForms.Count -gt 0) {
                    $existingForm = $list.Forms | Where-Object { $_.ServerRelativeUrl.ToLower() -eq $FormUrl.ToLower() }
                    if ($null -ne $existingForm) {
                        Write-Warning "  [Form Already Exists] $FormUrl"
                        return;
                    }                
                }
            }

            Write-Output "  [Adding Form Webpart] $FormUrl"
            #Get Webpart Manager for Form
            $wpm = $formPage.GetLimitedWebPartManager([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)

            #Import Webpart on page
            $wp = $wpm.ImportWebPart($webpartXml)

            #Add webpart to Form
            $wpm.AddWebPart($wp.WebPart, "Main", 1) | Out-Null

            #Execute changes
            $List.Context.ExecuteQuery()                    
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Error "Error creating form $FormType at $FormUrl. Error: $($_.Exception)"
        }
    }
    end { }
}
```

Use the script something like this.  If you only need to restore the EditForm, then you obviously you can skip the Upload, New, and DispForms below:

```
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $problemSiteUrl -UseWebLogin
    $list = Get-PnPList $problemlistTitle
    $listUrl = $list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl

    # Handle Document Library Types
    if ($list.BaseType -eq [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.BaseType]::DocumentLibrary) {
        Write-Host " > Processing Library: $listUrl"
        Create-DefaultListForm -List $list -FormUrl "$listUrl/Forms/Upload.aspx"   -FormType New
        Create-DefaultListForm -List $list -FormUrl "$listUrl/Forms/DispForm.aspx" -FormType Display
        Create-DefaultListForm -List $list -FormUrl "$listUrl/Forms/EditForm.aspx" -FormType Edit
    }

    # Handle Generic List Types
    else {
        Write-Host " > Processing List: $listUrl"
        Create-DefaultListForm -List $list -FormUrl "$listUrl/NewForm.aspx"  -FormType New
        Create-DefaultListForm -List $list -FormUrl "$listUrl/DispForm.aspx" -FormType Display
        Create-DefaultListForm -List $list -FormUrl "$listUrl/EditForm.aspx" -FormType Edit
    }
```

If you only need the Edit form, use the `Create-DefaultListForm` function like this:

```
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url 'UrlOfProblemSite' -UseWebLogin
    $list = Get-PnPList 'TitleOfTheProblemLibraryHere'
    $listUrl = $list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl

    Create-DefaultListForm -List $list -FormUrl "$listUrl/Forms/EditForm.aspx" -FormType Edit
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I just need EditForm. What is the Page_Type, Form_Type, Control_Mode I need to put in?  1048576 is a constant that I shouldn't change?

Comment: Yes, that is constant that specifies the built-in Form Type. If you see the switch statement inside the `Create-DefaultListForm` function, it figures out the values for you. If you just need the Edit form, then just call the function like this `Create-DefaultListForm -List $list -FormUrl "$listUrl/Forms/EditForm.aspx" -FormType Edit`

Comment: We used "{5CA...2DC7A }" in ListName and "5CA...2DC7A" in ListID. Keep getting   Object Reference Not Set to an Instance of an object                                          
Not Specified: (:)  NullReferenceException

Comment: You don't need to worry about the IDs directly, use the `$webpartTemplate` defined with placeholders just like in my post, don't replace those values yourself, along with the definition of `Create-DefaultListForm`, then call that function like my final example.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. We are using SharePoint 2013, the version should be 15..0.0.0?  We created a test document library to run the script to create an editform. If we don't provide list name and list id, will the script know which document library to create the Editform?  For $listUrl/Forms/EditForm.aspx, can we use an unique name, like $listUrl/Forms/EditForm10.aspx?

Comment: As long as the `-Url` parameter of `Connect-PnPOnline` is the url of your specific site, and the value you pass to `Get-PnPList` is the Title of your library, then yes, the script looks-up and determines the rest of the values for you.   Theoretically you can create as many different Edit Forms as you want with different names, but the built-in Edit buttons and Edit menu options will only every take the user to `/EditForm.aspx`, but you could have hyperlinks somewhere else that direct the user to different Edit Forms if you wanted to make customized ones.

Comment: I put our sandbox url for the -url and title of document library in the Get-PnPList, but still get Object Reference Not Set to an Instance of an object Not Specified: (:) NullReferenceException

Comment: After I installed Powershell PNP for SharePoint, I was able to create a new EditForm4.aspx. But got an error:                                                                   
Remove-PnPFile : Method "GetFileByServerRelativePath" does not exist.
At C:\Users\SPAdmin13SB\Desktop\SecLibEditForm.ps1:63 char:17
+                 Remove-PnPFile -ServerRelativeUrl $FormUrl -Force

Comment: EditForm4.aspx didn't exist before and it is the new form to be added, why the code run: Remove-PnPFile -ServerRelativeUrl $FormUrl -Force

Comment: Also in a couple of instances, the EditForm we wanted to create is: EditForm8,aspx. But it was actually created as EditForm8---010101-3.aspx.  Where did ---010101-3 come from?

Comment: This helped very much in a SharePoint Online environment. Thank you very much :)